# Changing element of malloc'd String in C?

Tags: c, string, malloc

After doing this,

```
char* example = (char*)malloc(10);
```

How can I change the 5th byte to 'a', so that `printf("%s", example);` would give me `"    a    "`?

Comment: What `malloc()` returns is not a string but an uninitialized buffer. You have to initialize it with some string first before changing the "string".

Comment: `a[4] = 'a';`. But you'll need to add those spaces too, and don't forget the null terminator (`a[9] = '\0';`). Also, there's no need to cast the result of `malloc()`. Try `char *example = malloc(10);` instead.

Comment: How to initialize all bytes to empty "          "?

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)  and... `memset (example, ' ', 9);` and `example[9] = 0;` Then `example[4] = 'a';`

Comment: Which book are you reading? The reason I ask is, this question you've asked indicates that you're struggling in a way which book readers usually don't... I'm suggesting that you're *not* reading a book, based on my observations. Am I correct?

Comment: *How to initialize all bytes to empty " "?* — `memset(example, ' ', 9); a[9] = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply like below:-

```
memset(example, ' ',10);
example[9] = 0; //assign end of string character equal to '\0'
example[4] = 'a';
```

How will it work? `memset` will fill all the bytes with white space and  `example[9] = 0;` will assign a end of string character into it and `example[4] = 'a';`
 will assign `'a'` at 5th location.

Answer (score 2):

The memory returned by `malloc` is unitialized.  Besides setting the 5th byte to `'a'`, you need to set the others to a space, and you'll need to add a null terminating byte.

The simplest way to do this would be `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(example, "    a    ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To change an individual element, just use regular array subscript notation:

```
example[4] = 'a';
```

Note, however, that `malloc` does not initialize the memory to be any particular value - it (most likely) won't be all blanks or all 0's.  It will be *indeterminate*.  If you want the elements surrounding `'a'` to be blanks, you'll have to assign them explicitly as well.  Also, remember to write the 0 terminator at the end, or `example` won't contain a *string*.

You can use `strcpy` to assign new strings to `example`:

```
strcpy( example, "    a    " ); // 9 characters plus string terminator
```

or you could assign element by element:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  example[i] = ' ';

example[4] = 'a';

for ( size_t i = 5; i < 9; i++ )
  example[i] = ' ';

example[9] = 0; // don't forget the string terminator!
```